# Extracting Way Point / Path of travel from revit 2020/2021

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

My Team have prepared a path of travel which they have presented us in revit 2020 application where they show us camera transition from point A to Point B.

Now this same thing we would like to do it in autodesk forge viewer.

I have tried extracting meta data of revit model using autodesk desk api and also have tried searching inside sqlitedb which but I was not able to find any useful information. here is the [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api) that i am referring to.

So I would like to know is there any option in revit software where I can export this data and use it or if this data goes with revit model then where can I find them in autodesk forge viewer

here is the reference [Link](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-Analyze/files/GUID-84C3AD28-8F10-4468-AD06-D740F81D7FC3-htm.html) which I am talk about.

I am open for some other solutions too for getting this requirement done

Comment: I am checking with the development team for you.

Comment: you can use revit api to draw model line base on that path, then translate model with it. What do you want to do with that data on Forge?

Comment: I am looking to show transition of camera using path of travel which is created in autodesk software

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the path of travel waypoint data is not stored in the metadata, unlike e.g. level and grid. Whereas the element properties are exported to the DB, they do not include the start, end or any other points, so the line currently cannot be drawn in the Forge viewer:

[image: Path of travel properties]

However, you could easily do as Paxton suggests, duplicate the waypoint data by creating a Revit model line element in the same location and adding some property to that so that you can recognise it as a placeholder for the path of travel in the Forge environment.

Alternatively, you could store your waypoint data anywhere else you please and add a representation of it in the Forge viewer yourself in any way you desire.

Comment: Thank @Jeremy. This was very helpful